# Angular Events, UI Blocked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am making a general loading animation for my angular application.

I have a service which toggles a loading animation on and off and the events are happening as I expect them to, my issue is that the UI is not updating with the events.

The turn on and turn off of the loading animation occurs in the same function call so my guess is that the ui isn't updated until the function call completes which basically means that my turning on and off or the loading animation has no effect.

How can I write this in a way that the UI will be updated as the variables change. I added in a pause to simulate heavy calculation on load just to check... which is the datetime stuff.

The two broadcasts are the start and stop of the loading state.

```
        function activateController(promises, controllerId) {

        var startData = { controllerId: controllerId };
        $broadcast(configcommonProvider.config.controllerActivateStartEvent, startData);
        return $q.all(promises).then(function (eventArgs) {
            var e = new Date().getTime() + (2 * 1000);
            while (new Date().getTime() <= e) { }
            var successData = { controllerId: controllerId };
            $broadcast(configcommonProvider.config.controllerActivateSuccessEvent, successData);

        });
    }
```

Comment: I ended up just manually manipulating the dom rather than using an angular expression for the loading behavior. It's not optimal but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling $apply() on your scope object after the broadcast, it should force a digest cycle which should update the UI.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the following if I attempt to $apply() or $digest()

    Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single-threaded and - conceptually - the changes in the GUI are on the same thread as the program.

This is exactly why there are so many callbacks in Javascript APIs (which you might have noticed working with AJAX). The only way to get around the single-threaded nature of JS is not to wait for something to finish at all. Instead - to be called back when something is finished.

What you want to do (long running calculations) is something very unnatural in JS, so the only real solution will be quite verbose. You need to run a webworker in parallel to your code and wait until it signals that it is finished. The shortest no-nosense example of using webworkers is probably the official HTML5 specification on WHATWG site.